# AJAX: Submitting a form without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form similar to the following:

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php" id="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="fname">
   <input type="text" name="lname">
   <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am new to AJAX and what I am trying to accomplish is when the user clicks the submit button, I would like for the `mail.php` script to run behind the scenes without refreshing the page.

I tried something like the code below, however, it still seems to submit the form as it did before and not like I need it to (behind the scenes):

```
$.post('mail.php', $('#myForm').serialize());
```

If possible, I would like to get help implementing this using AJAX,

Many thanks in advance

Comment: you need to prevent the default action. try prevent default function in jquery

Comment: @EdwinAlex Or just use simple `button` instead of `submit`

Comment: @DaHaKa we can change it also. But why should we need while having option in script itself.

Comment: Changing it in the markup makes some sense too - the Submit button is specifically to tell the form that it needs to submit. Using a button instead means that there is no default behavior to worry about stopping (e.preventDefault or return false) and is, overall, less Javascript.

Comment: The problem with changing the markup is that you remove the in built redundancy for anyone who has javascript disabled.

Comment: What @RoryMcCrossan said is extremely important. If you use the page with JavaScript disabled, and you use `button` instead of `submit`, the form will no longer work at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action (the actual submit).

```
$(function() {
    $('form#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.post('mail.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            // This is executed when the call to mail.php was succesful.
            // 'data' contains the response from the request
        }).error(function() {
            // This is executed when the call to mail.php failed.
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply. I would like to accomplish this using AJAX.

Comment: $.post is a shorthand method for $.ajax({method: 'POST'});

Comment: My solution *is* using AJAX :-) It says "When the form is submitted (`$('form#myForm').on('submit', ...`), post the data using AJAX (`$.post(...)`) and prevent the default submit (`e.preventDefault()`)".

Comment: Oh... :) oops. I see what your saying. The only problem is on success or fail orf the `mail.php` html is outputted to the screen, I would like that to be returned as it normally would be using $.ajax(), is this possible?

Comment: honestly speaking this answer helped me

Answer (score 4):

You haven't provided your full code, but it sounds like the problem is because you are performing the `$.post()` on submit of the form, but not stopping the default behaviour. Try this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('mail.php', $('#myForm').serialize());
});
```

Comment: +1 But I think a `return false` would be better (one less function call and property access)

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer personally I prefer `preventDefault()` as it does not stop event bubbling etc. `return false` is an absolute blunderbuss approach to stopping an event.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply. Can you please show how this can be done in Ajax?

Comment: @MHZ I don't understand what you mean - the code in my example will solve your problem, unless there's something else you mean?

Comment: The only problem is on success or fail orf the mail.php html is outputted to the screen, I would like that to be returned as it normally would be using $.ajax(), is this possible? something like `success: function(data){
$(".smart").html(data); ...`

Comment: `ReferenceError: e is not defined` - how shall `e` be defined to avoid this error?

Comment: Have you added in to the function call? `$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {` <--

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * it's better to always use the .on(event, context, callback) instead of the .submit(callback) or .click(callback)
 * for explanation why, try googling event delegation.
 */

//$("#myForm").on('submit', callback) catches the submit event of the #myForm element and triggers the callbackfunction
$("#myForm").on('submit', function(event, optionalData){
    /*
     * do ajax logic  -> $.post is a shortcut for the basic $.ajax function which would automatically set the method used to being post
     * $.get(), $.load(), $.post() are all variations of the basic $.ajax function with parameters predefined like 'method' used in the ajax call (get or post)
     * i mostly use the $.ajax function so i'm not to sure extending the $.post example with an addition .error() (as Kristof Claes mentions) function is allowed
     */
    //example using post method
    $.post('mail.php', $("#myForm").serialize(), function(response){
        alert("hey, my ajax call has been complete using the post function and i got the following response:" + response);
    })
    //example using ajax method
    $.ajax({
        url:'mail.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json', //expects response to be json format, if it wouldn't be, error function will get triggered
        success: function(response){
            alert("hey, my ajax call has been complete using the ajax function and i got the following response in json format:" + response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            //as far as i know, this function will only get triggered if there are some request errors (f.e: 404) or if the response is not in the expected format provided by the dataType parameter
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    })
    //preventing the default behavior when the form is submit by
    return false;
    //or
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to do this (which also doesn't require jquery) is to use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Older browsers [won't support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch), but there's a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch) if that's an issue. For example:

```
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
var params = {
  method: 'post',
  body: new FormData(form),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  }
};

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  window.fetch('mail.php', params).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.text());
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php" id="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
```

**OR**

add

`e.preventDefault();` in your `click` function

```
 $(#yourselector).click(function(e){
      $.post('mail.php', $(this).serialize());
      e.preventDefault();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default action if you are using input type as submit `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">`.

By putting `$("form").submit(...)` you're attaching the submit handler, this will submit form (this is default action).

If don't want this default action use `preventDefault()` method.

If you are using other than submit, no need to prevent default.

```
 $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'save.asmx/saveData',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      async:false,
      success: function() {
        alert("success");
      }
      error: function(request,error) {
        console.log("error");
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [JQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation. It should help you out.