# CodeIgniter : AJAX post data issue

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i have a problem with this simple login with ajax is when i click login the page refresh when it should not -_-

**My form**

```
<div class="user_login">
            <form action="<?php echo base_url('welcome/login');?>" method="post" id="login-usr-frm">
                <label>Email / Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="user"/>
                <br />

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" />
                <br />

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="remember" type="checkbox" />
                    <label for="remember">Remember me on this computer</label>
                </div>

                <div class="action_btns">
                    <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                    <div class="one_half last"><input type="submit" id="lgn-btn-red" class="btn btn_red" value="Login"></div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <a href="#" class="forgot_password">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>
```

***My jquery code***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $("#login-usr-frm").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var postData = $(this).serialize();

            $.post(url, postData, function (o))

        }, 'json');

        });

    });
</script>
```

i can't find the issue , please help ! :)

Comment: Check out the given link. It contains similar question [Ajax form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235596/ajax-submitting-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page)

Comment: please use the firebug....and check there is any jquery error coming...will loading the page...if coming then solve that first or put error jquery to bottom of the page ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to start Ajax using `$.ajax({ //ajax code });`

And Then put message in if condition to show success and error message

**Try this code below:**

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#login-usr-frm").submit(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var method = $(this).attr('method');
            var data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
               url:url,
               type:method,
               data:data
            }).done(function(data){
               if(data !=='')
                {
                    $("#response").show('fast');
                    $("#response").effect( "shake" );
                    $('#frm_login')[0].reset();
                }
                else
                {
                window.location.href='<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/login';
                throw new Error('go');
                } 
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: first thing you need to start ajax using $.ajax({  //ajax code  });

Comment: then I put message in if condition to show  succes and error message

Comment: correct if(data !=='') this line in your code it should be data!=" "