# submit a form without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that is responsible for inserting values in the database. It is working fine but when ever the values are submitted the page gets refreshed,  I tried to take help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235596/ajax-submitting-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page), but it didn't worked in my case. can anyone please tell how I can submit the values without refreshing the page.

Code that I have for now is

```
<?
    if($_POST['submit'])
        {
            $sender_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sender_id']);
            $receiver_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['receiver_id']);
            $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']);

            // execute insert query here
        }
?>

<form class="form-horizontal"  enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="sender_id" value="<? echo $recruiterid; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver_id" value="<? echo $recv_id; ?>">
    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" ></textarea>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-greensea btn-ef btn-ef-7 btn-ef-7b b-0 br-2"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Send Message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove/rename `name="submit"`, you are overriding default submit DOM method

Comment: And sorry for the dupe (not really checked it) but that's a wrong dupe, using click event of submit button instead of submit event of the form

Comment: @A. Wolff  k will check that, the link you have given under duplicacy.. i tried that, but my values are not getting carried to the other script through this code

Comment: *"Code that I have for now is"* - if that is your full code, you're missing the connection/query. If you are querying, check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php on your query and make sure you are using the same MySQL API to connect with as your functions. You also have not given us any JS/jQuery code here. Also make sure that short tags are enabled `<? echo` and if not, you'll need to change all of those instances to `<?php echo` and `<?` as `<?php`.

Comment: Plus, if you're using your entire code in the same file, you're probably trying to echo before anything was assigned. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: well, this question seems to have gone stale.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AJAX to submit forms without refreshing. Add this in your JavaScript:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function () {
    alert("Submitted!");
  });
});
```

Comment: tried but not working, i am not getting the alert message

Comment: What's happening in the console? Check using F12.

Comment: ajax is not getting loaded, getting a blank view

Comment: Getting a blank view? Where?

Comment: Why this has been downvoted? It looks legit

Comment: Even I am not sure...

Comment: @darcy I guess issue is because `$(this).serialize()` doesn't include `input type submit and you are checking using `if($_POST['submit'])` server side. I'm still not sure why you would need that. Anyway, you have to debug your code and see what's going wrong. FYI, again, you should `Remove/rename name="submit"`

Comment: @darcy Can you try using `count($_POST)` than `$_POST['submit']`?

Comment: Not my downvote neither, but the OP hasn't provided enough code here, including their JS/Ajax (being anybody's guess at this point). I've left a few comments under their question, and in regards to checking for errors.

Comment: I don't know if I should delete my answer for having a worthless downvote or try and continue to solve the problem of OP, who left off long back I guess.

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's your call. OP should be posting full code from the get-go.

Comment: I'll wait for a while, till I get frustrated, then I will be either getting it off, or deleting my answer. LoL. Let's see.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I know the feeling. I usually like to give them the benefit of the doubt for like.... 5 mins. which is my usual span of attention ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96984/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-fred-ii).