# Wordpress basic 'bootstrap' code for plugin development

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, plugins

I have made code (on a local machine) using Brackets and Theseus plugin. Everything works fine there. The problem is when I try to take it to a Wordpress installation.

There are many pieces to doing this; and, unfortunately, what I can get to work in Brackets in 10 minutes seems to take 100 hours to put into Wordpress. Is there some kind of basic "bootstrap" code or some kind of plugin out there that will allow one to get their code in to wordpress (on either the Admin side or Front-end side) easily - given one has a .js file, an index.html (or index.php) file, a .css file that allows for AJAX functionality to take place?

What would be good is to just make changes in files (i.e. variables) and filenames just to get going?

I guess the mods are going to try to down this question - but - I am just so sick and tired of trying to get my WORKING code into Wordpress.

Thanks!

Comment: kind of a odd rant, make your own template files or copy the codex or copy the 20xx series of themes, or plugins or whatever you are creating. Using a static method to create pages is ok once you know how its going to fit around the wp loop, but if you don't, it takes time to integrate. Anyway it sounds like you need to learn the loop, the various template options you can have and how to create custom posts/ taxonomies/ caching/ hooks/ filters. They are the most common items that you need to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. The problem was the implementation of AJAX under Wordpress.

These items helped me solve this problem:

How to implement jquery ajax in wordpress
        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipO3OrN6n2w

following tutorials here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cz-HImr6hQM

I would like to give ONE MILLION kudos to the guy who produced the "How to implement jquery ajax in wordpress" - it answered ALL my questions in just a few minutes.

Comment: FYI - the frustration that made me open this message was resolved with the link below. Chalk it up to being new in the JS space:  A MAIN PROBLEM I WAS HAVING WAS SOLVED WITH THIS
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235596/ajax-submitting-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page