# Change of div in the same page without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

In one of my pages, I have an `<a>` tag. When I click it, I am passing the variable as a `GET` parameter and retrieving it in the same page and displaying the details.

The code to get the parameters:

```
  if(isset($_GET['CatId']))
{   
$CatId= $_GET['CatId'];
}
else $CatId=0;
if(isset($_GET['MainProductId']))
{   
$MainProductId= $_GET['MainProductId'];
$FilterAllProductQuery ="WHERE Product.MainProductId = '$MainProductId'";
$FilterProductQuery = "AND Product.MainProductId = '$MainProductId'";
}
else 
{
    $MainProductId=0;
    $FilterAllProductQuery="";
    $FilterProductQuery="";
}
```

The `<a>` tag:

```
<a href='Products.php?CatId=<?php echo $CatId;?>&MainProductId=<?php echo $id;?>' ><?php echo $row["MainProdName"] ?></a>
```

The details to be displayed:

```
 if($CatId == 0)
                {$sql = "SELECT  *,Product.Id AS ProdId, Product.Name as ProdName  FROM Product $FilterAllProductQuery ";}
                else 
                {$sql = "SELECT  * ,Product.Id AS ProdId, Product.Name as ProdName FROM Product  INNER JOIN MainProduct ON MainProduct.Id = Product.MainProductId 
INNER JOIN Category ON Category.Id = MainProduct.CategoryId WHERE Category.Id = '$CatId' $FilterProductQuery ";}
   $result1 = $dbcon->query($sql);
                if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $id = $row["ProdId"];

                        // $image=$row["ImagePath1"];
                        $qty = $row["Quantity"];
                        ?>
              <li class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="product-box">
              <span class="sale_tag"></span>
            <div class="row">
  <img src='themes/images/<?php echo $row["ImagePath1"]; ?>'  height='200' width='250'> </a></div></div></li>
```

Now the code is working fine, but what's happening is that when I click the `<a>` tag, as I am passing the get parameters, the page is refreshing. As all the code are on the same page, I don't want the page to be refreshed. For that, I need to use **Ajax** request. How can I do that?

Comment: you can take reference from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I'm not super sure - since I'm not a php guy - but using #! in the should stop the page refresh

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Comment: you need to ajax for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634309/ajax-post-how-to-use-a-js-variable-in-php/42635488#42635488

Comment: ...geez I was mostly done retabbing this mess and it bumped me out because two other people had edited it.  Please do complete edits if you are going to bother.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an onclick() event on the a tag like so:

```
<?php echo '<a c_id="'.$CatId.'" MainProductId="'.$id.'" onclick="sendProduct()">'.$row["MainProdName"].'</a>';
```

Afterwards i would in a .js file write a simple function called sendProduct() and inside i would do an ajax request to a page named ex: insertproduct.php, get the information back and Insertproduct.php would process the data and you could use .html() or .append() to assign the data to the div showing the data with a normal id.

The c_id, MainProductId are custom attributes you could recieve in the .js file as $("#youraTag").attr("c_id");

There's a really good guide here on basic ajax: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XBeGcczFJo&list=PLQj6bHfDUS-b5EXUbHVQ21N_2Vli39w0k&index=3&t=1023s

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the href of the link and give it an id.

```
<a id='link'>
    <?php echo $row["MainProdName"] ?>
</a>
```

Then you put this jQuery into your page. Note, you need to have a div in which you are going to put in all your obtained results. I reffered to this div in the code as `#mydiv`.

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv").load("Products.php?CatId=<?php echo $CatId;?>&MainProductId=<?php echo $id;?>");
});
```