# Simple PHP AJAX script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 scripts, `submit.php` and `display.php`.

I want to be able to load `submit.php`, click the submit button & the `result` div to display `123`.

Right now, it just reloads my page. I'm not getting anything from my Console so stuck how to debug.

Can someone take a look and provide assistance?

**submit.php:**

```
<form>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="display" id="display">

</form>

<div id="result">&nbsp;</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#display").click(function() {                

    $.ajax({
      url: 'display.php',
      type: 'GET',          
      dataType: "html",
      data: {
         "id": "123",
      }, 
      success: function(data) {
      //called when successful
      $('#result').html(data);
      },
      error: function(e) {
      //called when there is an error
      //console.log(e.message);
      }
    });

});
</script>
```

**display.php:**

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. You're just submitting your form and reloading the page. You need to prevent the form from being submitted.

Comment: @j08691 I believe it reloads it even then.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why would it reload if the input wasn't a submit button?

Comment: @j08691 Wow. That was easy. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @j08691 Not sure. I had issues with that as well. `:(`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX: Submitting a form without refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235596/ajax-submitting-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page)

Comment: @j08691 It shouldn't but hitting enter in a textbox would probably still submit it, so preventing the form to submit via Javascript is probably the best solution. (Or removing the form tags could also help, but that might mess up custom css or something like that.)

Comment: @Ivar Yes, a form with a single text box would submit, however that's not the case here.

Comment: @j08691 This might just be a mcve and not the complete form. You never know. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It submits or reloads the page. You need to prevent the default action. Change the first two lines:

```
$("#display").click(function(e) { // Add e (event) parameter.
  e.preventDefault();             // Prevent the default action for this event.
```

You *may* change to `type="button"`, but not sure if it will be effective.

Comment: *"You may change to type="button", but not sure if it will be effective."* - I'm sure it will ;-)

Comment: It sure is - just tested it :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk LoL. Thanks for confirming it. `:)` I had issues in implementing it myself. I should be messing with something or missing something.

Comment: inputs tend to refresh/load, as opposed to a button with a submit type in JS. I am not a JS guru, but do know that much LOL! @PraveenKumar

Comment: @PraveenKumar when in doubt, try them both ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**solved your issue please**

```
  replace
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="display" id="display">
    by 

    <button type="button" name="display" id="display">Submit</button>
```